# I want to remove footer from all pages except home page of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove footer from every pages except my homepage.I have used this code but it is not responding

```
.page #footer {
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not responding? It removes the footer on every page, or it doesn't remove the footer on any page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show the footer only in your home page, depending on your template where it calls the footer function include this condition

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) // check if it's the homepage
    {
    get_footer(); // include the footer
    }
?>
```

but be careful because most of JS files are called in the footer part, so make sure all your js scripts are included site wide

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.page` part.
It should just be:

```
#footer{
display:none;
}
```